# Can we measure the height of clouds using the sunset?

Tags: visible-light, refraction

I was watching the sun set in San Francisco. As the Earth turns away from the Sun the tallest buildings remain lit longest. Light bending in the atmosphere allows this to last a bit longer. So, what about clouds, which still reflect light for a certain fixed amount of time after a building of a known height stopped reflecting. Can we calculate their height using a Sunset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, though the accuracy might not be the best because clouds don't exactly have hard edges and it might be hard to differentiate between the red light from scattering and the tail end of the reddened sunlight hitting the clouds.

Refraction might have an effect too, though thinking about it, I don't think this would change the calculation much.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_refraction

So, lets get to the calculations, using this article as a guideline:

http://gizmodo.com/5917230/did-you-know-that-the-burj-khalifa-is-so-tall-that-you-can-watch-two-sunsets-on-the-same-day

The Burj Khalifa is 828 meters tall and it gets 3 minutes more light every sunrise and sunset.   If we're going to use this as our measuring stick, every extra minute of the sunlight corresponds to 216 meters in height.    So every Kilometer in the air, About 5 more minutes of direct sunlight.

I'm sure the article rounded out the time so this isn't super accurate, but it's a ballpark answer.